# RIDE installation: robot --version failing

Tags: python, pip, robotframework, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install robotframework on my system having OS CentOS 7.

I have installed python

```
 python --version
 Python 2.7.5
```

pip is installed

```
pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

robotframework is installed

```
pip install robotframework
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): robotframework in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However, when I am checking robot installation, I am getting below error

```
robot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/robot", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('robotframework==5.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'robot')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/rebot.py", line 40, in <module>
from robot.conf import RebotSettings
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/conf/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from .settings import RobotSettings, RebotSettings
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/conf/settings.py", line 89
raise DataError(f'Invalid option{s(opts)} {seq2str(opts)}.')
```

Any idea what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should uninstall that version and use Python 3 (like @jiri-janous mentioned).

```
sudo pip uninstall robotframework
sudo yum install python3 python3-pip
sudo python3 -m pip install robotframework
```

Note: For RIDE installation, see its [project pages and FAQ](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at he Instalation [instructions](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#installation-instructions). I would suspect that you need at least python 3.6
from the resource:

> Robot Framework requires Python 3.6 or newer. If you need to use
> Python 2, Jython or IronPython, you can use Robot Framework 4.1.3.